# Set datepicker startDate jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am not able to set the startDate parameter to a datePicker.

I was trying to look for a solution and came up with nothing that works.

What i need is to set default value to the datePicker (1/1/1970) and when I click it I want it to show me the date of today.

This is what I came up with, although it's not working:

```
$(".from-date").datepicker( "setDate" , "1/1/1970" );
$(".from-date").datepicker("option", { startDate: "1/1/2015" } );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your date first as default date and on textbox selection fire jquery for change default date of datepicker and set today's date as default date

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
   $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '1/1/1970');

 $('.datepicker').click(function(){
   var myDate = new Date() ;
 $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
});
```

[Here Is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DK7mU/6)

Answer (score 2):

Use this [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DK7mU/6/)

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', '1/1/1970');

$('.datepicker').click(function(){
    var myDate = new Date() ;
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
});
```

Comment: tnx coding cracker, but i need it to show 1/1/1970 but when i click the input to open with startDate of today

Comment: check now @omri_saadon

Comment: @CodingCracker Sorry to say that, but you copy my comment and make it as your answer, pls check my comment. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put a minDate in the datePicker that will disable all the dates before this minDate.

Find the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DK7mU/10/)

```js
  $(function() {
      var todayDate = new Date();
      //$('.datepicker').datepicker();
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
          minDate:"01/01/1970"
      });
      
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate", todayDate);
      
  });
```